# Passing cyrillic text as JSON from localStorage via jQuery Ajax to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax, character-encoding

I try to insert JSON string from localStorage via jQuery Ajax to MySQL

My **send.html** (in local PC):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#send').click(function() {
    var tableValue = 'mytable';
    var passValue = 'mypassword';
    var dataKey = 'mydatakey';
    var dataValue = localStorage.getItem('mylocalstoragekey');
    // dataValue is JSON string like {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}
    var dataValue = dataValue.split('"').join('\'');
    $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      url: 'http://mywebsite.com/run.php',
      cache: false,
      data: {table: tableValue, pass: passValue, key: dataKey, value: dataValue}
    }).done(function(data) {
      alert('Data saved');
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

My **run.php**:

```
<?php
$table = $_REQUEST['table'];
$pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];
$key = $_REQUEST['key'];
$value = $_REQUEST['value'];
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mydbname;host=localhost', 'mydbuser', $pass);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.$table.'` (`id`, `key`, `value`) VALUES (1, "'.$key.'", "'.$value.'");';
    $db->exec($sql);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql.'<br>'.$e->getMessage();
}
$db = null;
?>
```

It works but there are the following three problems:

1. `var dataValue` (i.e. `$value` in **run.php**) as JSON string has cyrillic text in my localStorage but it's being inserted to MySQL not in UTF-8; I tried `header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');` in my run.php but it didn't help
2. I don't get `alert('Data saved')` on my **send.html** page
3. How to pass JSON via Ajax properly? (as you can see I replace double **"** with single
   **'** before passing via Ajax but it's not the best way probably)

Answer (score 1):

PDO needs the charset:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mydbname;host=localhost;charset=UTF-8', 'mydbuser', $pass);
```

The table/column needs `CHARACTER SET utf8`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with Unicode settings on your Mysql. Also you run.php has SQL injection.